# How to make VS Code organize Java imports like IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for Java development and working with other developers who use IntelliJ. I'd like to use the Organize Imports command (Shift+Alt+O) to clean up my imports, but I don't want to fight over import order with every commit. So I'd like to configure VS Code to organize the imports in the same order as IntelliJ's default. Does anybody have a configuration that would do this?

If this is not possible, is there a workspace configuration I can apply to both VS Code and IntelliJ so that the two IDEs will agree, even if they aren't agreeing on IntelliJ's default?

Comment: "The same order as IntelliJ" is not well-defined because the order is configurable within IntelliJ. (Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports)

Comment: Updated to reflect that I'm going for IntelliJ's default, which is these groups separated by newlines: [*], [javax,java], [static]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We were able to get it the *almost* identical with the following config tweaks.

VS Code:

```
{
  "java.completion.importOrder": [
    "",
    "javax",
    "java",
    "#"
  ]
}
```

IntelliJ
[image: IntelliJ import order]

The only difference from the IntelliJ default is a new line between `import javax...` and `import java...`.

Comment: So `""` represents everything and `"#"` represents static imports? Nice! How did you find this?

Comment: Good question. I tried to find my source, but I couldn't find it again. I believe I found it in Eclipse JDT's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get VS Code and IntelliJ to agree on a standard format, as long as that standard format:

1. <del>Puts static imports at the top</del>*
2. Separates all specific sections with empty lines
3. <del>Puts everything not in its own specific section in a catch-all section at the end</del>*
4. Never uses wildcard imports

   - Not actually true; static imports can be positioned in VS Code with `'#'`, and everything else can be position in VS Code with `''`.

IntelliJ's default settings don't work for this, but it is flexible enough to be reconfigured. Here are the files to add to a *project* to make just that project set up consistent rules for both IDEs (make sure they are not excluded in `.gitignore`).

Rule: The following groups separated by empty lines: Static imports, `java.*`, `javax.*`, everything else.

.vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "java.completion.importOrder": ["java", "javax"],
}
```

.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml:

```xml
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />
  </state>
</component>
```

.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml

```xml
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <code_scheme name="Project" version="173">
    <JavaCodeStyleSettings>
      <option name="CLASS_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="99" />
      <option name="NAMES_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="99" />
      <option name="IMPORT_LAYOUT_TABLE">
        <value>
          <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="true" />
          <emptyLine />
          <package name="java" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
          <emptyLine />
          <package name="javax" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
          <emptyLine />
          <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
        </value>
      </option>
    </JavaCodeStyleSettings>
  </code_scheme>
</component>
```